# TTS - leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: android

I am using the TTS in my APP. During onPuase method, I use the following code to stop the engine. The problem is whenever I pause the activity say using home button, I get the error as I have pasted in the log cat section. I understand from the log cat (Activity com.example.DragDrop.PlaySeries has leaked ServiceConnection ) the problem is due to some leakage. However the issue is not stoping my app or disturbs any functionality. But I would like to know the seriousness of this issue and how to avoid this ?

Please help

```
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();   
    Log.i("PlaySeries", "In pause play series");
    if(tts !=null){
        Log.i("PlaySeries", "In pause play series");
        tts.stop(); 
    //  tts.shutdown();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {  
    //Close the Text to Speech Library
    if(tts !=null){
        Log.i("PlaySeries", "In pause play series");
        tts.stop(); 
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and in onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.series);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
}
```

### LogCat

```
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): Activity com.example.DragDrop.PlaySeries has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@2bbe5960 that was originally bound here03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.DragDrop.PlaySeries has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@2bbe5960 that was originally bound here03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.DragDrop.PlaySeries has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@2bbe5960 that was originally bound here03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881): 
 03-22 10:46:45.205: E/ActivityThread(3881):
```

Comment: where do you have tts.shutdown()?

Comment: I don't have that. If I have shutdown, then when I come back to the app I am not having the service of TTS..

Comment: done.. This solved my problem.., I will accept ur answer ..

Comment: I wrote the answer so other people with same problem can easily read it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just have this code `onDestroy`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    tts.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar error when I made the TTS object static (so the TTS continues speaking even when the device is rotated). The leak was triggered when the device was rotated so the screen changed between portrait and landscape modes.

For a while I was perplexed as the error was only reported on some older devices running earlier versions of Android. However once I discovered the fix I suspect the problem was common to all devices and versions, but possibly masked on the newer models.

The fix was to initialize the TTS object with the Application Context, rather than the current (Activity) context.

Here's my code
 `tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);`

and the complete diff is available at: 
http://code.google.com/p/android-tts-experiments/source/detail?r=b879fd1042151cbebc736b89a9fb660c895081ea

Comment: Excellent point. If Activity which called TextToSpeech is destroyed (but TTS not necessarily shutdown e.g. I am using TTS from MyService and Activity is used only to initialize TTS) THEN there will be ServiceConnection leak.

Comment: Great solution, I had a custom toast class that would use TTS to speak the contents of the toast when displayed.  This was being called from service.  This solved my problem with a leak.  THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Here is my TurnKey solution for TTS from outside an activity / in a service...

If you can not use onDestroy, simply listen for when it is done speaking then shutdown and stop TTS.  Use the application context to prevent the leak.  Here ya go.

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by acopp
 * Date: 1/11/2017.
 * Time: 6:11 AM
 * You have permission to use this file for any reason that is not for evil doing
 */

class SpeakThis{
    private Context mContext;
    private TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech;
    private String mTextToSpeak = "";
    private boolean mSpeechAvailable = false;

    SpeakThis(String text,Context context){
        mTextToSpeak = text;
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();//THIS WILL FIX THE LEAK  THANKS TO JulianHarty

        mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(mContext, mTextToSpeechListener);
        mTextToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mUtteranceListener);//NO ON DESTROY NEEDED JUST LISTEN FOR UTTERANCE STATUS
    }

    void talk(String talkThis){
        mTextToSpeak = talkThis;
        if(mSpeechAvailable){
            speak();
        }else{
            mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(mContext, mTextToSpeechListener);
            mTextToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mUtteranceListener);
            mTextToSpeech.setSpeechRate(0.75f);
            mTextToSpeech.setPitch(1.2f);
        }
    }

    private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener mTextToSpeechListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                        result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS","SPEECH NOT AVAILALBE");
                    mSpeechAvailable = false;

                } else {
                    if(mTextToSpeak.length() > 2){
                        speak();
                    }
                    mSpeechAvailable = true;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
                mSpeechAvailable = false;
            }

        }
    };

    private void speak() {

        if (mTextToSpeak.length() > 0) {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mTextToSpeech.speak(mTextToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null,"toastText");
                } else {
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    mTextToSpeech.speak(mTextToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            } catch (Exception ignore) {

            }
        }
    }

    private UtteranceProgressListener mUtteranceListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String s) {//STOP AND SHUTDOWN TTS WHEN COMPLETED TALKING
            try {
                mTextToSpeech.stop();
                mTextToSpeech.shutdown();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s) {

        }
    };
}
```