# Resolving TTS Memory Leak detected with LeakCanary

Tags: android-studio, memory-leaks, text-to-speech, back-button, leakcanary

This is the description of a memory leak detected by LeakCanary: (it occurs when the Android back button is pressed)

```
1 APPLICATION LEAKS

    References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
    Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

    356182 bytes retained by leaking objects
    Displaying only 1 leak trace out of 2 with the same signature
    Signature: 2276fec44ae233e0d5bb5b82648d5836c07e3b33
    ┬───
    │ GC Root: Global variable in native code
    │
    ├─ android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection$1 instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Anonymous subclass of android.speech.tts.ITextToSpeechCallback$Stub
    │    ↓ TextToSpeech$Connection$1.this$1
    │                                ~~~~~~
    ├─ android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ TextToSpeech$Connection.this$0
    │                              ~~~~~~
    ├─ android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ TextToSpeech.mContext
    │                   ~~~~~~~~
    ╰→ com.example.price.SignUpDisplay instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.price.SignUpDisplay received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
    ​     key = 6965e004-28de-464b-87d7-2668461623e7
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 30282
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 25282
```

This is how tts is initialised in my activity:

```
protected fun initializeTextToSpeech() {
        mtts = TextToSpeech(this, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
            // If a success, set the language
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                res = mtts.setLanguage(Locale.UK)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Feature not supported in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        })
    }
```

This is the onDestroy method:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        if (mtts != null) {
            mtts.stop()
            mtts.shutdown()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Why is there a leak and how can I fix it?

I also get this warning in the logs - I'm not sure how bad it is or if it relates to the leak at all:

```
W/TextToSpeech: stop failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563361/tts-leaked-serviceconnection/20863947

Comment: They seem to recommend putting tts.shutdown() in onDestory(), which is what I have.

Comment: They also mention the practice of initializing the tts using the application context instead of the activity context... which is what I think may solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `TextToSpeech` keeps a strong reference the context provided in its constructor, a `Connection` instance is keeping a strong reference to the `TextToSpeech` instance (since it's its outer class) and a native reference is keeping a reference to the `Connection`.

One way to fix this is to have bind the TTS service using an application context instead of the activity context.

In `initializeTextToSpeech()`, instead of:

```
    mtts = TextToSpeech(this, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
```

Try this:

```
    mtts = TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear response! However, I am still getting the same error. Is what I'm doing in onDestroy sufficient? I also use the TTS instance in fragments - would that cause an error? For example, I'll call (activity as BaseDisplay).mtts.speak() within a fragment.

Comment: You shouldn't get exactly the same error if you do that fix, but maybe another similar error which means doing the same fix somewhere else?